# Mailgun Webhook Access

Tags: webhooks, mailgun

We're currently implementing Mailgun's webhook to convert an email reply to a reply in a comment thread in our application. We set up a route to match the recipient and set the action to `store(notify="https://example.com/example-endpoint")`. Mailgun POSTs data to the given endpoint where we then process the message and add it to the application comment thread.

**My question is this**:

How do I lock down the endpoint so that Mailgun is the only entity that can post here? Is there a list of IPs that I can whitelist? Is there a special key that they send that I can validate against the private API key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer in the documentation. I should have read the documentation more closely.

The "Securing Webhooks" section under https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#webhooks says:

> To ensure the authenticity of event requests, Mailgun signs them and posts the signature along with other webhook parameters.

I had to compare the `signature` value in the payload to a SHA256 HMAC hash of `timestamp` and `token` using the api key as the HMAC key.

For example:

```
$_POST['signature'] === hash_hmac('sha256', $_POST['timestamp'] . $_POST['token'], 'example-api-key);
```